# Jacoco coverage and Kotlin default parameters

Tags: java, code-coverage, kotlin, jacoco

I am having the following constructor:

```
open class IPFS @JvmOverloads constructor(protected val base_url: String = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/",
                                          protected val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build(),
                                          protected val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()) {
```

Now when measuring coverage I always get misses for when defaults are used. The only way out I can imagine is to write some tests in java that use the other constructors - but I would like to stay in pure kotlin - is there a way to do this?

[image]

Update: I am using constructors like IPFS() in my tests - but I think on the generated java bytecode this is converted to the constructor with all 3 parameters - and this is the only thing jacoco sees

Comment: Technically, you have four constructors in byte code, and you call only one of them. This would be the same as in Java.

Comment: I am calling different constructors - but only one is seen by jacoco

Comment: Ah, so it's the other way around. Makes sense.

Comment: how do you know you call different constructors? From kotlin only one should be visible (the one with the matrix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/#jvmoverloads) annotation, the compiler will generate 3 overloaded constructors. This annotation is mainly used to be able to omit parameters in plain Java.

> ```
> @Target([AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR])
> annotation class JvmOverloads
> ```
>
> Instructs the Kotlin compiler
>   to generate overloads for this function that substitute default
>   parameter values.
>
> If a method has N parameters and M of which have default values, M
>   overloads are generated: the first one takes N-1 parameters (all but
>   the last one that takes a default value), the second takes N-2
>   parameters, and so on.

When calling the constructor with any number of parameters in Kotlin, the default 3-parameter constructor will be invoked - where the [default values](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) are used for parameters that are omitted.
Thus it makes sense that Jacoco does not mark the overloads as covered: they're not.

Like @voddan said, these overloads are generated, and guaranteed correct. It doesn't make much sense to test these separate.

If you do want full coverage however, remove the `@JvmOverloads` annotation. This should prevent the additional overloads from being generated.

If you can't remove the annotation because you will be calling the overloaded constructor from Java, then having a Java test suite that covers these makes sense after all: it's a real world scenario you want covered.

Comment: technically the "default 3-parameter constructor" has 4 parameters (the last one is mask)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need a 100% coverage on those constructors? Those constructors are auto-generated by the compiler, which guaranties their correctness (to a bigger extend than code coverage).

IMO it is enough to test the constructor with all custom parameters. An additional test for all default parameters may cover the calculation of the default values.

Overall, testing an auto generated code may be not the best idea.

Comment: I would like to have a high overall coverage percentage

Comment: @ligi Adding unnecessary magic to your code only to get betters numbers in reports is bad practice and you should avoid it. Just make sure your most important methods are covered.